# Model is null in API controller after being submitted from Angular frontend

Tags: c#, angular, api, .net-core

I have a Angular with .Net Core project, it's very simple in nature, the app just lists people also allows for someone to add a person.

However when I submit a new person the model in the controller is always null.

Here is my Angular-Post method:

```
 public async onSubmit(value: any, valid: boolean, isLive: boolean) {

 const model = {
   ...value,
 };

 console.log(JSON.stringify(model));

 try {

   const header = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-type', 'application/json');

   var success = this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl + 'person', JSON.stringify(model), { headers: header }).toPromise();

   if (success) {
     console.log('wooo');
   }

 }  catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
 }

}
```

Logging the model to the console shows me the following data:

```
{"Firstname":"john","Lastname":"Doe","Gender":"2","DateOfBirth":"29/09/1955"}
```

However in the API controller I see the following:

[image]

Can anyone recommend or suggest why this comes through as null? I've tried removing the `JSON.stringify` but the issue persists.

Hitting the end point via *Postman* as suggested in the comments the model is populated with the data. Below is the *Postman* body:

```
{
 "Firstname": "frefrefre", 
 "Lastname": "dewdewdew", 
 "Gender": 1, 
 "DateOfBirth": "2019-01-06T17:16:40"
}
```

Seems submitting from the Angular frontend sets the **Gender** variable to a `string`, and the **DateOfBirth** to an *incorrect format*..

Comment: Do you use default .net core JSON converter or newtonsoft.json?

Comment: hey @SergeyAnisimov I haven't specified either within the project.

Comment: Also, did you try to post the same model from a tool like Postman? If yes, does it work?

Comment: remove `[FromBody]` in your action

Comment: Hey @SergeyAnisimov I have just tried, updated the post with my findings.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the `[FromBody]` unless you are also passing *URL data* in the **same call**, the issue would appear to be something wrong with the server interpretation of the content type/headers.

Try making the header collection exactly the same as it is in the Postman test.
Also it might be worth simplifying the code a little to trace the issue:

```
const headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json'}  
const body=JSON.stringify(model);
console.log(body)
var success = this.httpClient.post(this.baseURL + 'person', body,{'headers':headers})
```